# 7up in Spanish speaking countries

Tags: traducción

When I first went to Argentina a long time ago I spent 5 minutes trying to ask the person at the bar in a club for a glass of **"Siete up"** until they eventually understood that I wanted a glass of **"Seven up"** and I felt pretty stupid...

So my question is:

Do all Spanish speaking countries call 7up, **"Seven up"**?

I'm guessing that the adverts on TV for '7up' call it by the English name so everyone else does too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in Argentina, as you already know, it's called *Seven up*.

*Sprite* is also pronounced the very same way as in English. The same bartender will also have some trouble trying to serve you a Sprite if you told him that you wanted a *Sprite* as it would sound in natural Spanish. If Sprite wasn't a well known brand but a common word, it would have surely already been naturalized as *Sprait*.

*Fútbol* for example, is a naturalized word, that has its root in the English word football, but was transformed in such a way that when pronounced it keeps the original sound of its English root.

*Cederrón* is another example of a naturalization of another English term, or in this case acronym, CD-ROM, that sounds almost the same as the original term in its original language. The only difference would be the ending *n*, that I guess was transformed from an *m* to avoid the word ending in *m* which is an unnatural ending in Spanish.

Comment: Thanks. The reason i didn't expect 7up to be naturalized was because of the fact that the seven is always written as the number not the word =) But I suppose with media such as TV and radio, you frequently hear it as well as read it.

Comment: In Mexico, both 7-Up and the 7-Eleven convenience store are usually called simply *Seven*, and Sprite is pronounced as *Esprait*.

Comment: In Perú is also "seven up". I'm not 100% sure, but from my experience only in Spain they try to convert to spanish everything. In Latin America you keep english pronuntiation usually.

Comment: In Chile we also say "seven up".

Comment: I've heard "WiFi" pronounced the English way in some countries, and the Spanish way in others.